# Mocking in Wordpress unit test

Tags: php, wordpress, testing, phpunit

The function I'm testing requires another plugin, but I want to test it in isolation without having that plugin activated.

```
function functionName() {
   ...
   if (!is_plugin_active('path/to/plugin.php')) {
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

How can I simulate that call returning true when I write a unit test?

Comment: Please refer this. I thing it will help you http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the 'active_plugins' option during your tests to include that plugin.

See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L434.